# Trying to consume API data from Django backend to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, axios

I am trying to consume the Bing web search api. I have my view setup in Django backend. I was able to retrieve the search result data in terminal. But I am getting an error when fetching the data in React. If you could please help with a detailed response it would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

#### Django runserver terminal when refreshing React page:

```
  
                         'name': 'iPhone 13 review | Tom&#39;s Guide',
                         'noCache': False,
                         'primaryImageOfPage': {'height': 80,
                                                'imageId': 'OIP.63KzaXCF-d8nPkQdmM6bWgHaDL',
                                                'thumbnailUrl': 'https://www.bing.com/th?id=OIP.63KzaXCF-d8nPkQdmM6bWgHaDL&w=80&h=80&c=1&pid=5.1',
                                                'width': 80},
                         'snippet': 'The<b> iPhone 13</b> is a great '
                                    'budget-friendly flagship phone with a '
                                    'brighter display, longer battery life and '
                                    'powerful cameras. Read our in-depth '
                                    'review to find out its strengths and '
                                    'weaknesses, and how it compares to the '
                                    'iPhone 14 and other models.',
                         'thumbnailUrl': 'https://www.bing.com/th?id=OIP.63KzaXCF-d8nPkQdmM6bWgHaDL&w=80&h=80&c=1&pid=5.1',
                         'url': 'https://www.tomsguide.com/reviews/iphone-13'}],
              'webSearchUrl': 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=iphone+13'}}
Internal Server Error: /home/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\storm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\storm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\storm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
[22/Mar/2024 14:15:37] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 500 72597
```

SearchResults.js React file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const SearchResults = () =\> {
const \[data, setData\] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/home/`);
    
                setData(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        };
    
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My Component</h1>
            {data ? (
                <ul>
                    {data.map((item) => (
                        <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );

};

export default SearchResults;
```

views.py inside of bing_api (app folder):

```
def home(request):
  url = 'https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search'
  search_url = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search"
  search_term = 'iphone 13'

  headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": API_KEY}
  params = {"q": search_term, "textDecorations": True, "textFormat": "HTML"}
  response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
  response.raise_for_status()
  search_results = response.json()
  data = response.json()
  pprint(data)

  #below is to view in React
  pages = search_results['webPages']
  results = pages['value']
  # pprint(results\[0\])
  return results
```

url.py folder:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = \[
path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
\]
```

Comment: The stacktrace is not complete :(

Comment: Otherwise the error message is quite straightforward, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595050/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-get